# Creating input object for mcl algorithm

Tags: r, igraph

Having a dataset like this:

```
dframe = data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), date = c("2013-07-14T21:44:37", "2017-09-18T12:04:06", "2014-08-13T19:17:55", "2016-04-17T07:45:54", "2014-11-19T08:05:26", "2013-06-27T05:48:02", "2017-03-07T08:40:31", "2018-05-20T13:37:22", "2014-08-31T07:33:38", "2011-04-05T14:11:51", "2014-06-19T16:27:29", "2016-10-24T21:59:17", "2013-04-30T06:49:54", "2011-08-04T20:27:33", "2011-10-31T07:45:49", "2012-03-03T23:29:02", "2018-05-19T09:48:13", "2018-02-25T20:42:00", "2016-12-08T05:03:17", "2015-05-21T23:26:41", "2015-07-16T12:38:33", "2015-08-09T17:15:39", "2017-10-14T05:38:04", "2017-09-23T06:11:29", "2015-07-11T02:46:40", "2017-12-17T04:14:08", "2015-06-14T02:28:37", "2017-12-16T02:17:07", "2018-02-26T06:35:26", "2016-12-14T22:27:04", "2016-12-22T23:31:51", "2016-12-20T01:49:41", "2017-08-28T11:39:42", "2015-06-15T00:51:13", "2015-09-02T15:02:53", "2018-05-02T19:07:45", "2015-10-26T22:11:16", "2015-10-28T09:37:02", "2018-02-10T07:58:27", "2015-05-05T13:21:20", "2018-04-25T19:09:41", "2016-03-30T08:06:27", "2017-10-31T12:09:44", "2016-11-04T13:46:06", "2015-09-02T15:02:12", "2016-09-01T14:54:16"), course = c("computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", "computer", "chemistry", "history", "history", "history", "history", "history", "parallel", "parallel", "poetry", "italics", "italics", "italics", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "mathematics", "mathematics", "mathematics", "poetry", "poetry", "poetry", "gym", "motion", "computer", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "literature", "physics", "poetry"))
```

The id column is the user who changes a course preference, which is the third column based on time which is the date column. So the preference of the course is the transfer/states.

How is it possible to create an appropriate input for [mcl algorithm](https://micans.org/mcl/)?

Example of expected input using an example of mcl package:

```
library(MCL)



mat <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,
       0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), byrow=TRUE, nrow=9)
```

> ```
> mat
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
>  [1,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
>  [2,]    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
>  [3,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
>  [4,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
>  [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
>  [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
>  [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
>  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
>  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
> ```

Comment: Is that the correct output for the input example

Comment: @akrun I added an example. I need a matrix based on course preference transfer. For example if there a transfer computer-> history this combination takes 1 if the transfer based on time is computer-> computer computer take 1

Comment: if I look at your input, at the 7th row, computer -> chemistry. and there are only 3 ids.  so can you explain about the dimensions of the output

Comment: @akrun based on the unique number of course

Comment: But, that is 11 `uniqueN(dframe$course)#
[1] 11`

Comment: @akrun I am sorry akrun the expect output for a transition matrix is for this example 3 row, one for every id, and column will be the combination of all possible transitions https://chortle.ccsu.edu/FiniteAutomata/Section06/sect06_2.html

Comment: I can't replicate it.  May be `lapply(split(dframe[-2], dframe$id), function(x) {+(crossprod(table(rleid(x$course), x$course)) > 0)})`